# User Deleting Row on Datatable (Automatically Removes Row)

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I have a `DataGridView` called `Contracts`.

I have a method for `Contracts_UserDeletingRow` which performs a number of steps..

Firstly it produces a `MessageBox` to confirm the action. If confirmed - the row is removed and everything works perfectly.

However, if the user selects `Cancel`, the row is automatically removed from the view. **Not deleted server-side, just hidden.**

To fix this issue I tried this;

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete?", "Verify Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)

{Update the record in background...}

    else { GetContractLevels(); this.Activate(); }
```

The `GetContractLevels()` method refreshs the view from the source, how come it doesn't execute? When I then run the same method from a button click - it works.

Comment: Have you verified that the program flow is as you state, by using a debugger?

Comment: The `else` condition is `response != DialogResult.OK`. In that case, the database is not updated at all; therefore, even if you did refresh from it you should not expect to see a change.

Comment: We need to see GetContractLevels()

Comment: @AdamKewley I'm aware the database isn't updated - but the row disappears from my DataGridView until I refresh it again.

Comment: @RB. I haven't the row is only disappearing from the view - nothing else. I will look into the debugger now.

Comment: @Derek The method is fine and works on every other execution, I'm fairly sure it just isn't being called.

Comment: If the row is disappearing  from your `DataGridView` when the source has not yet been updated I would suspect that `GetContractLevels()` or `Activate()` are performing a UI update independently of the actual database model.

Comment: As RB mentions, it would be best to ensure your program flow is as stated by adding a breakpoint into the `true` block of that `if` statement.

Comment: @AdamKewley Yes - this is purely a UI issue as if I don't call GetContractLevels() or Activate() - the same thing still happens.

Comment: @Clev231 In that case, I suspect the problem is somewhere else in your code - perhaps you are removing the row from the DataGridView manually somewhere else?

Comment: Are you using a `BindingSource` as datasource of the `DataGridView`?

Comment: The row isn't being removed anywhere else. My datagridview allows the deleting of rows (UI only of course) and this is what I want to avoid if the dialog result is 'cancel'. My datasource is a datatable - filled from a SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `e.Cancel = true`:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete?", "Verify Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
{  Update the record in background...  }
else { 
    e.Cancel = true;//Do this to cancel the physical deleting row of user
    GetContractLevels(); 
    this.Activate(); 
}
```

Comment: I worked out another way but this is cleaner - thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a dataset? If so, then you can look at your Main() function, below the InitializeComponent() there should be a line, which loads the data into your datagridview. Kindly use that code to update your datagridview, so that when the user cancels the transaction, the datagridview will be updated as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I'm refreshing the source inside the deleting method which means that it refreshes but then removes in anyway added the following method solved it.

This refreshes after a row has been removed.

**However, King King has a more clean solution in my opinion.**

```
private void Contracts_UserDeletedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                GetContractLevels();
            }
```